# Possible to replace all nulls on report (all columns) with custom value?

Tags: obiee

Does anyone know if there is a setting in answers to replace multiple columns containing null values with 0 (or some other custom value)?

A user put several reports on a dashboard page and now wants to see nulls replaced with 0's. Obviously we can add ifnull(fact,0) to each affected column but with the number of reports we're looking at, it would require over 100 columns to be changed.

I've looked into this on the RPD side but our aggregation rule sums the values and we are using an inner join so the ifnull is essentially ignored. We also would not want to create a new fact column in the RPD derived from these facts.

Your help with this is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is probably to set custom formatting on the column, in which you can [format the display of null values](http://www.clearpeaks.com/blog/oracle-bi-ee-11g/setting-custom-data-format-in-obiee-answers). The other option, as you suggest, would be to edit each column of each analysis.

From the criteria of an Analysis, edit the column properties and set the data format of the column to a custom format with a mask of `#,#.0;-#,#.0;0` (or `#,0;-#,0;0` depending on your preference for precision).

You can then apply that formatting as the default for all columns with that source, or to all columns of that data type using the "Save as Default" option from the same dialog. For the former you will need to set the formatting once for each measure column you wish to affect.

Comment: Bad use of terminology on my end. The "reports" are actually several analysis'. I understand what you suggested and it would work very well for multiple reports on a single analysis. I don't think we can tie that formatting into multiple though :(

Comment: @user3661576 see the third paragraph in my answer. By setting the default formatting you will affect any Analysis using "that column" from "that subject area", or every column on the whole environment with that datatype, depending on the option you choose.